# Cracks on tire - still safe to ride?

Tags: road-bike, tire, tire-pressure, crack

I just experienced some uncommon cracks on the tires (Schwalbe Durano Plus)

The tires are pretty new (less than half year old, and used max. 1500 km).

I inflated 6 bars in the tire, and according to the specs 6-8 bars should be normal.
Is it possible that this cracks are caused by overinflation? 
Should I immediately replace them or is it still safe to ride like this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't actually see any cracks in your photos: they're probably more obvious to you because you're familiar with the tread pattern and construction of the tyres. Could you add some arrows pointing to the cracks?

Comment: Ah, there's a crack right along the rim, likely due to running at too low of a tire pressure.  It's hard to tell how serious it is.  Probably safe for day-to-day use, but I'd replace it before you start out on that trans-Canada ride.

Comment: Sorry for the bad picture quality. Yes, as Daniel said they are along the rim. Low pressure could be the reason, as I used it a few times with around 3 bars of pressure. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It's probably safe, but personally I wouldn't ride it with potential damage that close to the bead.  If it were to fail, it would be very difficult to bodge a 'get me home' fix compared to a tear closer to the tread.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  If you see the inner tube herniating out, then its time to get off immediately.   If you're concerned then feel free to add a boot to the inside of the tyre at that point, just to get some more use out of the tyre before replacement.   However I've ridden much worse for much longer.

Comment: Looks more like a delamination of the tire to me - the rubber isn't cracking, it's coming loose from the casing.  Where are you storing your bicycle when not riding?  It doesn't look like [ozone cracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_cracking), but maybe it is.  Is it both tires or just one?  I'd still ride on that tire, but I'd be watching it closely, expecting to replace it soon, and I'd have more than one tire boot with me on all rides.  And I wouldn't put that tire on a front wheel - because you **will** lose control of your bicycle if your front tire blows at any decent speed.

Comment: (cont) FWIW, underinflation is a known cause of delamination.  If you know that's what caused the delamination, I'd replace the tire immediately, as the entire tire is likely close to falling apart now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of tire cracking that is most worrisome is when it's accompanied by bulging areas from the tube pressure. This implies damage to the casing, which in turn implies a tire that might very realistically fail at any time. The casing is the major structural part of the tire, not the rubber.

Cracks in the rubber like this look bad but almost never result in any issues themselves. When they do, usually its actually something along the times of the casing getting damaged in some kind of incident or condition that also caused the rubber cracking.

There's some distant hypothetical risk that the crack makes the casing more vulnerable in that spot or causes some kind of stress riser, but basically it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve had this issue with reflective sidewall stripes as well. They are less flexible and tend to crack the sidewall at the edges of the stripe. As others have said, cracks usually only affects the rubber, the casing below should be unharmed. It’s mostly a cosmetic problem.

Cracks in the thread can decrease puncture resistance. For the sidewalls this isn’t really a concern.

Usually low tire pressure will *increase* the likelihood of cracks. Cracks are caused by repeated deformation due to low pressure. Aging and UV light also make the tires more brittle. Puncture resistant tires with thick, inflexible rubber are usually more prone to cracks.